# vaadin TreeTable remove dropdown on parent without children

Tags: vaadin, treetable

I'm using vaadin's TreeTable. Is there a way to remove or hide the dropdown arrow on the first level objects that do not have any children and still have the objects correctly positioned vertically?

**UPDATE**

Final solution if anyone is interested:

I add a FieldFactory to the table

```
protected class TableFactory extends DefaultFieldFactory{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private MyTreeTable table;
    public TableFactory(MyTreeTable table){
        this.table = table;
    }

    @Override
    public Field createField(Container container, Object itemId,
            Object propertyId, Component uiContext) {
        Field field = super.createField(container, itemId, propertyId, uiContext);

        if(itemId instanceof TaskHeadRow){
            if(((TaskHeadRow)itemId).getTask() instanceof SystemTask){
                table.setChildrenAllowed(itemId, false);
            }
        }

        return field;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arrow is not show if you define for the item:

```
treetable.setChildrenAllowed("myitemid", false);
```

Comment: Correct answer. But that blocks adding new items as children to that item. In this case i think i'll have to remove it by css. or put the first column size 1 or 2 px